# how can I replace %23 with # in url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

when I click on submit button url is:

```
http://localhost/college/index.php?field=1&exam=ATMA&submit3=%23success
```

I want to replace this link with:

```
http://localhost/college/index.php?field=1&exam=ATMA&submit3=#success
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: When you submit, is your backend expecting the value for `submit3` to be `#success`?  If so, don't change it, handle it in the backend.  A `#` has special meaning.  it would be like trying to get `submit3=&success` to have submit3 = `&success` - you'd need to encode the `&` in the same way that `#` is encoded here.

Answer (score 3):

The functions you are looking for are

PHP:

```
urlencode($string);
urldecode($string);
```

Javascript:

```
decodeURIComponent(string);
encodeURIComponent(string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following `decodeURIComponent`:

```
decodeURIComponent('http://localhost/college/index.php?field=1&exam=ATMA&submit3=%23success')
```